# "App Updates is running" warning happening very often

Tags: applications, lg, 7.0-nougat, lg-g5

This week I upgraded to Android 7.0 and since then, everytime I turn on mobile data and enter/exit an app, this notification appears

[image: "App updates is running" notification].

> App Updates is running
>   Preparing to install apps...

I unchecked all types of notification in Google Play Store, but nothing happens. Is someone experiencing this as well and maybe know a fix? The device it's LG G5.

Answer (score 0):

Open the LG Update Center (on the V20 it's under the Common tab in "About Phone") and set notification interval to Never.  If that doesn't do it, reopen Update Center and install every app listed.  Then uninstall the ones you don't want.

I'm guessing the update center initially tries to install these apps and isn't satisfied until it's done.